# Looping over a Date or POSIXct object results in a numeric iterator

Tags: r, date, for-loop, attributes, posixct

Why does iterating through a `Date` or `POSIXct` object result in `numeric`?  For example:

```
test = as.Date("2009-01-01")
print( class( test ) )
# [1] "Date"
for ( day in test )
{
    print( class( day ) )
}
# [1] "numeric"
```

The same thing happens with `POSIXct`:

```
test = as.POSIXct("2009-01-01")
print( class( test ) )
# [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
for ( day in test )
{
    print( class( day ) )
}
# [1] "numeric"
```

Comment: as.numeric(test) is essentially the same result. ie, the number of days from epoch 1970-01-01.

Comment: This would work: `for(d in as.list(test)) print(class(test))`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck has the right answer to what should have been the primary question -- which is how to make `for` do what virtually everyone really wants it to do with a (vector? list?  whatever) of dates.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`?"for"` says that `seq` (the part after `in`) is "[A]n expression evaluating to a vector (including a list and an expression) or to a pairlist or 'NULL'".

So your `Date` vector is being coerced to `numeric` because `Date` objects aren't strictly vectors:

```
is.vector(Sys.Date())
# [1] FALSE
is.vector(as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
# [1] TRUE
```

The same is true for `POSIXct` vectors:

```
is.vector(Sys.time())
# [1] FALSE
is.vector(as.numeric(Sys.time()))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Pretty close, but I'm afraid that but there is no coercion in a for loop here, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23278464/3309529).....

Comment: @gagolews: That's a very subtle distinction that few people will understand or appreciate. Yes, `for` doesn't strip attributes and call `coerceVector` on the iterator (and potentially create a copy). It simply ignores the attributes. Regardless, the practical effect is the same. Had I said "treated as" instead of "coerced to", you wouldn't have had a point to make.

Comment: It would be less confusing to admit that Date objects _are_ "vectors" in the sense that most people understand the term, but with an attribute which is lost. For instance, `is.atomic(SysDate())` returns `TRUE`. The really surprising notion for me anyway was that for-loops will traverse lists.

Comment: @BondedDust, that is probably because if you do `is.vector(as.list(as.Date("2009-01-01")))` it will return `TRUE`

Comment: So that's the reason why it's sometimes good to study the source code - the manual does not explain all the nuances. Indeed, as Joushua mentioned, from a plain user's point of view this is not so important. But it's good to have some insight.

Comment: @gagolews: And don't misunderstand my comment, it's an interesting point, but I just don't think most people will care. ;)

Answer (score 24):

loop through days (strings):

```
     days <- seq(from=as.Date('2011-02-01'), to=as.Date("2011-03-02"),by='days' )
     for ( i in seq_along(days) )
     {
          print(i)
           print(days[i])
      }
```

Answer (score 19):

You are not choosing the right function to apply to `Date` vectors when using for-loops. Better would be wrapping `seq_along` for pretty much every date or factor that is being looped across. Then you will do two thing: a) set it up so you are expecting an index that starts at 1, and b) protect against strange things that occur with zero length vectors. I also think it would be better to use it with factors, which the for-loops will turn into character vectors.

With reference to Joshua's answer (which is certainly correct and helpful), I think the `is.vector` function is a bit mislabeled or maybe just misunderstood. It could be more accurately be called `hasNoAttributesOtherThanName`. The property that most people consider "vectoric" is tested with `is.atomic` and `Date` and `POSIXct` objects will return `TRUE` from that test.

Comment: +1 especially for `hasNoAttributesOtherThanName`, though I think it should be named `has_no_attributes_other_than_name`. ;-)

Comment: Your 'a)' point is valid, but regarding 'b)', the docs for `for` say "If `seq` has length zero the body of the loop is skipped."

Comment: In this case it might not make a difference but in the case what the person was using 1:length(x) they get iterations that they should not want to get. Safer to use seq_along().

Answer (score 9):

It seems that the C function that implements the `for` loop does not copy any of the vector's attributes. This also includes the `class` attribute, which should make `i` appear to be a `Date` object.

You may study the source code of the `do_for(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)` function (the one called by R's `for`) [here](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-devel/eval_8c.html#ac9c8ee03eab1b3545cd1fa5a746385a9).

Answer (score 6):

It is an old question, but I am a novice on R and faced the same problem. Since my problem would be processed in parallel, I used [foreach](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/index.html) and saw the behaviour is different when compared with the normal `for`:

```
library(foreach)

start_date = as.Date("2013-08-1")
end_date = as.Date("2013-08-13")
days = seq(start_date, end_date, by = "day")

foreach(day = days, .combine='rbind') %dopar% {
  print(class(day))
}

[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
[1] "Date"
...
```

As I am not experienced with the inner things of most of R, thus I do not know why `foreach` ends up having a different behaviour but that worked for my purpose, and hopefully might be useful for someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Any numerical operation on date objects generally returns the number of days. In this, you are asking it to provide you with the number of days from the epoch. 14245 which is the number of days between 1970-01-01 - 2009-01-01

From ?Dates:

> Dates are represented as the number of
>   days since 1970-01-01, with negative
>   values for earlier dates. They are
>   always printed following the rules of
>   the current Gregorian calendar, even
>   though that calendar was not in use
>   long ago (it was adopted in 1752 in
>   Great Britain and its colonies).
>
> It is intended that the date should be
>   an integer, but this is not enforced
>   in the internal representation.
>   Fractional days will be ignored when
>   printing. It is possible to produce
>   fractional days via the mean method or
>   by adding or subtracting (see
>   Ops.Date).

Try adding `print(day)` to see what I mean.

```
test = as.Date("2009-01-01")
print( class( test ) )
for ( day in test )
{
  print(day)
  print( class( day ) )
}
```

Comment: hmm...which numeric operation am I performing?  I'm simply using a for loop.  If I use a for loop from i:length(test) and then call test[i] then I get a Date.  Its not intuitive to me why the "for-each" would result in numeric

Comment: If you want to loop through the number of days, use `for(1:as.numeric(test))`

Comment: Your present for statement is just returning the number of days between test and 1970-01-01. Or, `day:test` but what you really want is something like `1:day:test`

Comment: I guess I'm just not seeing it.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I read "for ( day in test )" as "iterate through each element in test and assign the value to variable day"

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen - `for(1:as.numeric(test))` doesn't iterate through the number of days in `test`, it starts at Jan 1, 1970, and counts forward the number of days elapsed until the day `test`.

Comment: @Ken, by setting 1:as.numeric(test) you're telling it to start at 1, hence Jan 1, 1970.

Comment: Right, but that's not often a useful thing to do.  1970 wasn't *that* great a year. ;-)  @SFun28 was interested in iterating through the multiple entries of `test`, not from some external start date to `test`.  And if `test` has length more than 1, `1:as.numeric(test)` issues a stern warning and discards all but the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution per-se, but a useful trick when you want to check the dates in a loop:

for( i.date in as.character(Sys.Date()) ){
cat(paste("Date:", i.date, "\n"))
}

just transform it as character beforehand. Most filters won't bother.