# Why is the epoch date correct, but does not work as an offset for POSIXct objects?

Tags: r, date, posix, epoch, posixct

I have a vector of POSIXct objects:

```
> dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2004-01-01", tz="EST"), as.POSIXct("2004-01-02", tz="EST"), as.difftime(6, units="hours"))
> dates
[1] "2004-01-01 00:00:00 EST" "2004-01-01 06:00:00 EST"
[3] "2004-01-01 12:00:00 EST" "2004-01-01 18:00:00 EST"
[5] "2004-01-02 00:00:00 EST"
```

I create an `epoch` variable that defines a POSIXct object for the [UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time):

```
> epoch <- strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="EST")
> class(epoch)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"  
> epoch
[1] "1970-01-01 EST"
```

I then loop through the `dates` vector and print out the value, offset from `epoch`:

```
> for (d in dates) { print(as.POSIXct(d, origin=epoch, tz="EST")) }
[1] "2004-01-01 05:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 11:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 17:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 23:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-02 05:00:00 EST"
```

There seems to be a five-hour offset error between the values in `dates` and the representation of those same values, relative to `epoch`.

There is a +5 hr difference between EST and UTC, but I specified the EST time zone for `epoch` with the `tz` option. Printing out `epoch`, there doesn't seem to be the time information, only the date.

Is there a bug with `strptime` or `as.POSIXct`, or am I calculating the offset or generating `epoch` incorrectly?

Comment: The (-) five hours is in your epoch, the UNIX epoch is GMT not EST.  Why do you even want to do this?  `dates` is already a respectable POSIXct / POSIXt object.

Comment: Here, I am defining the epoch as relative to EST, not GMT. Thus, offsets to dates that are EST should not require that correction (unless I misunderstand how `strptime` works). I am exploring this question and I am curious why I am getting the wrong answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750075/for-loop-style-has-effect-on-class-coercion

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the answer to [For loop style has effect on class coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8750075/for-loop-style-has-effect-on-class-coercion), in the `for` loop, your dates are converted to numbers.  That is the number of seconds since the "standard" epoch. This includes the 5 hour shift between EST and UTC. That is added as an offset to your `epoch`.  See the source of `as.POSIXct.numeric`.

The following does work because it sets up dates which will be the right number of seconds when converted to numeric.

```
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2004-01-01", tz="UTC"), 
             as.POSIXct("2004-01-02", tz="UTC"), 
             as.difftime(6, units="hours"))
epoch <- strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="EST")

for (d in dates) { print(as.POSIXct(d, origin=epoch, tz="EST")) }
```

Which gives

```
[1] "2004-01-01 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 06:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 12:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-01 18:00:00 EST"
[1] "2004-01-02 EST"
```

Comment: `strptime` does return a `POSIXct`, see `?strptime`

Comment: Huh.  When I look at `?strptime` it says (in the Details section): "`strptime` converts character vectors to class `POSIXlt`". This is R-2.14.1. That is consistent with the return value I see (via `class(epoch)` or `dput(epoch)`).

Comment: I am using R-2.13.0 (2011-04-13) and the description for `strptime` is as follows: "Functions to convert between character representations and objects of classes ‘"POSIXlt"’ and ‘"POSIXct"’ representing calendar dates and times." When I run `class(epoch)` it returns the type I expect (`POSIXct`).

Comment: I didn't realize that the return value had changed. I edited my answer to remove my incorrect comment about that.