# Looping through vector of dates seems to change their type - how to fix?

Tags: r, datetime, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [R - why does looping over a Date object result in a numeric iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/r-why-does-looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator)

I have the following R code which produces a vector of dates in a certain range:

```
library(lubridate)
start_date = ymd("2009-07-25")
end_date = ymd("2010-11-30")
dates <- seq(from=start_date, to=end_date, by="1 day")
```

If I look at the structure of the dates vector I get the following:

```
> str(dates)
POSIXct[1:494], format: "2009-07-25" "2009-07-26" "2009-07-27" "2009-07-28" "2009-07-29"...
```

and if I look at the structure of an element of the vector I get:

```
> str(dates[5])
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2009-07-29"
```

All what I'd expect so far. However, if I do a for loop through these dates and look at the structure I get:

```
> for (d in dates) {str(d)}
 num 1.25e+09
 num 1.25e+09
 num 1.25e+09
 num 1.25e+09
```

They've all changed to numerics! I have two questions:

1. Why is this happening? Is it something I've done wrong, or is an R feature?
2. How can I stop this happening, so I get a POSIXct instance inside my for loop

Comment: 1) it's how for loops work in R. 2) You can't. Better to loop over the index of `dates`: `for(i in seq_along(dates)) d <- dates[i]`.

Comment: See also [How to iterate over list of Dates without coercion to numeric in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527564/how-to-iterate-over-list-of-dates-without-coercion-to-numeric-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)