# How to iterate over list of Dates without coercion to numeric?

Tags: r, list, date, for-loop

This is related to [Looping over a Date or POSIXct object results in a numeric iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-datetime-object-results-in-a-numeric-iterator)

```
> dates <- as.Date(c("2013-01-01", "2013-01-02"))
> class(dates)
[1] "Date"
> for(d in dates) print(class(d))
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

I have two questions:

1. What is the preferred way to iterate over a list of Date objects?
2. I don't understand Joshua's answer (accepted answer from the question linked above), I'll quote it here: "So your `Date` vector is being coerced to `numeric` because `Date` objects aren't strictly vectors". So how is it determined that `Date` should be coerced to `numeric`?

Comment: What I meant by my comment is: `is.vector(dates) # FALSE`, so Dates are not "vectors".  Your second question should really be a comment to my previous answer.

Comment: So clearly `dates` is not a vector, and clearly it is `Date`. But what is it that makes it behave like a vector. What is it that makes it iterable?

Comment: The `for` loop coerces it to a vector.

Comment: From the help page  `?vector`. "For any mode, it [`is.vector`] will return FALSE if x has any attributes except names." In R-speak a "vector" does not mean that it can be accessed by position, but rather that it doesn't have attributes. It specifically states that factors are not vectors and it probably should also have stated that Date and POSIXt classed objects are not either.

Comment: To answer question 1. You can leave `dates` as a character vector and coerce within the loop or use the `seq_along()` technique noted in the post you linked... (or one of the answers below)

Comment: So `dates` could be a list of `Date` objects. Why did `for` decide to coerce it to a vector of numbers? Is there such a thing in R as a vector of `Date`s?

Comment: Nope, see @DWin's comment above regarding the definition of vectors in R.  Dates need attributes, like origin, to have any meaning.  Unless you wanted a vector of lists of dates... or something silly like that! `is.vector(c(list(as.Date('2013-01-01')), list(as.Date('2013-01-02'))))`... But I don't think that helps at all

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich @DWin I don't think that is a standard definition of vector. Dates are vectors, but the `is.vector` function is confusing - it tells you if you have an atomic vector that does not have attributes. `is.atomic(as.Date("2012-01-01"))` is TRUE so Dates are atomic vectors.

Comment: @hadley: I agree, which is why I put "vectors" in quotes. It's also why, in the previous question, I said they "aren't _strictly_ vectors" (emphasis added).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two issues here.  One is whether the input gets coerced from `Date` to `numeric`.  The other is whether the output gets coerced to `numeric`.

**Input**

For loops coerce `Date` inputs to `numeric`, because as @DWin and @JoshuaUlrich point out, `for` loops take `vectors`, and `Date`s are technically not vectors.

```
> for(d in dates) print(class(d))
[1] "numeric"
[1] "numeric"
```

On the other hand, `lapply` and its simplifier offspring `sapply` have no such restrictions.

```
> sapply( dates, function(day) class(day) )
[1] "Date" "Date"
```

**Output**

However!  The output of `class()` above is a character.  If you try actually returning a date object, `sapply` is not what you want.

`lapply` does not coerce to a vector, but `sapply` does:

```
> lapply( dates, identity )
[[1]]
[1] "2013-01-01"

[[2]]
[1] "2013-01-02"

> sapply( dates, identity )
[1] 15706 15707
```

That's because `sapply`'s simplification function coerces output to a vector.

**Summary**

So:  If you have a `Date` object and want to return a non-`Date` object, you can use `lapply` or `sapply`.  If you have a non-`Date` object, and want to return a `Date` object, you can use a `for` loop or `lapply`.  If you have a `Date` object and want to return a `Date` object, use `lapply`.

**Resources for learning more**

If you want to dig deeper into vectors, you can start with [John Cook's notes](http://www.johndcook.com/R_language_for_programmers.html#vectors), continue with the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf), and continue with [SDA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441926127).

Comment: `sapply` does, because of `simplify2array` (matrices can only hold atomic vectors).  You're returning the class, not the object itself.  Try:  `sapply(Sys.Date(), identity)`.  `lapply` works though.

Comment: What about `> sapply(dates, class)` that prints `[1] "Date" "Date"`? Shouldn't `sapply` coerce to numeric vector? (according to the post and comment)

Comment: @user443854: as I said, that's returning the class of the object (a character string, which is an atomic vector) as it exists inside the function call; it's not returning a Date.  Would you allow me to give you $100 as "$100"?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: class of the object is character string whose value is "Date". But the actual object is numeric. Why the mismatch?

Comment: @user443854: I don't know how else I can explain it... `simplify2array` coerces it to numeric, for reasons I've already explained. So `sapply` returns a number, not a Date, even though it's still a Date inside the function.

Comment: Ok, so I'm really confused now.  Was the question how to iterate over a date pseudo-vector (what does one even call this?) without the *input* being coerced to numeric, or how do you *return* a collection of dates?  My assumption was the former, since that is what the for loop has trouble with.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich matrices are not limited to atomic vectors: `matrix(list(1, 2, 3, 4), nrow = 2)`. I think the really explanation that either `simplify2array` is poorly written, or the Date class is missing needed S3 methods.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman are you confused about my question? I can clarify that. I certainly do not need to return a collection of dates, since this is what I start with; `dates` is a list of `Date`s. If your confusion is about pseudo-vectors (the onese @JoshuaUllrich puts in quotes), then I am also still confused. First part of my question was practical, to solve immediate problem. Second was attempt to get a clear picture (still not there). @hadley hints something is poorly written -- it really looks like that.

Comment: @user443854 My reading of the question was that you wanted the **Input** part of my answer.  It seems like that worked for you?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: Yes. But I am still missing coherent explanation of the coercing behavior. If `Date` becomes `numeric`, what about other arbitrary types? It would be nice to hear someone explain the purpose for this behavior (or maybe acknowledge this is a kink in the language).

Comment: @user443854 The behavior is entirely consistent: If it's a `vector` (see `is.vector()` to test), then it works.  If not, it doesn't.  There's more info out there on R fundamental data types.  Someone here can probably recommend a book (likely featuring yellow and blue prominently on the cover and written by Chambers) that will teach you more.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman: It troubles me that `for` does not work (using your language) for non-vectors (e.g. lists). In fact, as we learned, it coerces a list of `Date`s to numeric vector. My question is why? And where is consistency here? (If this is too much to answer here, please point me to a book/chapter to read, I am totally for it!) Thanks.

Comment: @user443854 I assume there's some technical reason why relating to the underlying C code.  I also assume they never really bothered to fix it because it would a) make things a little slower, and b) loops aren't very R-like in the first place.  The `*apply` family commands handle this just fine, and they're what you should be reaching for in the first place.  *Edit* added some references for you to dig deeper.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman I did not bother to buy the book from Amazon, but I did read the first two references and found them... pretty irrelevant. As for `apply`, it is implemented using `for` loop, take a look. As @hadley points out, `Date`s *are* atomic vectors, they just happened to have attributes, so that poorly written `is.vector` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman @user443854 no, it is not consistent, and it is because `for` is written in C and does not look at the class of the object, or use `[` to extract individual components of the vector.