# Munging dates in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, data-munging

I'm working on a data-munging pipeline with a lot of date columns in the data. Many R functions (e.g., set operations, `sapply`, etc.) do no preserve date class, converting the dates to integers.

The strategies I see to deal with this are:

1. Making sure that each function in the data-munging pipeline accepts and returns dates formatted as dates. Disadvantage: figuring out all the places to stick `as.Date()` is often tedious.
2. Living with dates as integers in all the munging steps, converting them to dates only at the end. This has the disadvantage of making date manipulation (e.g., sequencing with `by = "month"`) in the intermediate munging steps impossible without first converting to date.

Any other options I'm missing? Is there a way to make R play nice with dates? To clarify, the data I'm dealing with is not just a time series: multiple columns contain dates. So, as far as I can tell, `xts` is of limited usefulness.

Comment: A third option would be to live with dates as integers, unless you need them as a date class for a specific data munging step, e.g. when you need `by = "month"`.This might be a compromise between (1) and (2) that is less tedious, less error prone because you don't assume on automatic casting, yet flexible enough to do your munging chores.

Comment: Perhaps [How to iterate over list of Dates without coercion to numeric in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527564/how-to-iterate-over-list-of-dates-without-coercion-to-numeric-in-r) and links therein can be helpful. And the good'ol [`ifelse` "trap"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects)...

Comment: Thanks Henrik -- that's helpful. PS. Why was the question marked off-topic? I could add code for a few of the operations that don't preserve dates, but I doubt it would improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *does not preserve `Date` class* misfeature is an artefact of R itself, and how some base R functions are implemented. See *e.g.*

```
R> dates <- Sys.Date() + 0:2
R> for (d in dates) cat(d, "\n")
17532 
17533 
17534 
R>
```

Essentially, the S3 class attributes gets dropped when you do certain vector operations:

```
R> as.vector(dates)
[1] 17532 17533 17534
R>
```

So my recommendation is to pick a good container type you like and stick with it to do the operations there.  I like [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki) *a lot* for this. A quick example:

```
R> suppressMessages(library(data.table))
R> dt <- data.table(date=Sys.Date()+0:2, other=Sys.Date() + cumsum(runif(3)*100))
R> dt[, diff:=other-date][]
         date      other           diff
1: 2018-01-01 2018-03-30  88.88445 days
2: 2018-01-02 2018-06-09 158.23913 days
3: 2018-01-03 2018-07-30 208.62187 days
R> dt[, month:=month(other)][]
         date      other           diff month
1: 2018-01-01 2018-03-30  88.88445 days     3
2: 2018-01-02 2018-06-09 158.23913 days     6
3: 2018-01-03 2018-07-30 208.62187 days     7
R>
```

Not only does the `Date` type persist (as evidenced by the difference operation returning a `difftime` object), but you also gets lots of helper
functions (like `month()`) here.  Grouping by date is also natural.

Comment: I agree the lack of support for dates is a misfeature, but I don't see how `data.table` is relevant.  I can do those operations outside of `data.table` and get the right answer.

Comment: With all due respect you seem to misunderstand what the question is.  See eg this question (already linked above) about [preserving Date type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527564/how-to-iterate-over-list-of-dates-without-coercion-to-numeric-in-r). You have no such issues with `data.table` which is why I find it convenient. As another plus, `data.table` solutions tend to be fast.  But there are many different ways to skin the cat and if you have one you like better, by all means stick with it.

Comment: But your own example fails:  `cat(dt[1, "date"], "\n")` doesn't do any better than `cat(dates[1], "\n")`.

Comment: Use `format()` for display.  Same story on `Date` class attribute being dropped. You still misunderstand _and the original question was on processing pipelines, ie many dates at once_ and your griping here has nothing to do with that.  So please stop it.

Comment: I agree, you should use `format()` for display, because `cat()` loses the class.  But I still don't understand how `data.table` helps:  I need to use `format()` to display an element from one of those too.  I'm not griping, I'm asking for clarification.  But if it upsets you too much, feel free to ignore the request.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not hard to replace the calls to `sapply` with a function that does what you want.  For example,

```
sapply2 <- function(X, FUN, ...) {
  do.call(c, lapply(X, FUN, ...))
}
```

This isn't as general-purpose as the original `sapply`, but if the function you're using in `sapply(X, FUN)` returns dates, it will preserve them.  If you want to use the optional arguments to `sapply`, you'll need something more elaborate.

I don't know how many other functions are in your "etc.", but I'd guess it's not very many, and most fixes aren't all that hard.

Comment: Nice on the `sapply`! Besides the set operations, `unlist` and `ifelse` come to mind. I can certainly work around those, so indeed "fixes aren't hard", but it's very annoying to have to remember to apply those fixes everywhere in ones program. To me, this is one of the obvious weaknesses of types in R.