# Date shows up as number

Tags: r, postgresql, date

I have fetched a set of dates from postgresql, they look correct:

```
[1] "2007-07-13" "2007-07-14" "2007-07-22" "2007-07-23" "2007-07-24"
[6] "2007-07-25" "2007-08-13" "2007-08-14" "2007-08-15" "2007-08-16"
etc.
```

Then I want to run a loop on them to make new sql sentences to fetch some other data sets (yes, I know what I am doing, it would not have been possible to do all the processing in the database server)

So I tried

```
for(date in geilodates)
 mapdate(date,geilo)
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "13707"
LINE 1: ...id_date_location where not cowid is null and date='13707' or...
```

mapdate is a function I have written, the use of date within that is

```
sql=paste('select * from gps_coord where cowid=',cowid," and date='",date,"'",sep='')
```

So, what has happened is that R silently converted my formatted dates to their integer representations before i tried to paste the sql together.

How do I get the original textual representation of the date? I tried

```
for(date in geilodates){
  d=as.Date(date,origin="1970-01-01")
  mapdate(d,geilo)
}
Error in charToDate(x) : 
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

And I have not managed to find any other functions to create a datestring (or to "serve" the date as the string I get when listing the variable

Comment: Could you show both `dput(geilodates)` and the full `mapdate` function?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/r-why-does-looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to wush978 for pointing me in the right direction, In the end I had to do:

```
for(d in geilodates){
 date=format(as.Date(d,origin="1970-01-01"))
 mapdate(date,geilo)
}
```

For some reason, inside the loop the "date" variable was seen as an integer, so I explicitely had to convert it to a date and then format it...

Comment: "...for some reason" is because `is.vector(Sys.Date())` is `FALSE`. `help('for')` says: "seq: An expression evaluating to a vector...or to a pairlist or 'NULL'", so what happens is (essentially) `as.vector(Sys.Date()) # 15729`.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshuaUlrich! That clearified it. (jsut hope I remember that until the next time I need it ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

try `?format.Date`

```
x <- Sys.Date()
class(x)
class(format(x))
```

In R, the data of class `Date` is a numeric type.
An official way to represent `Date` as string is to call `format`.

I doubt that the format of `date` is defined in your case, so `paste`
does something unexpected.

Maybe you need to put `format(x, "%Y-%m-%d")` in your `paste` function instead of `date` to tell R how which format you want for Date.

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I needed, but this is weird, I can do:

 date=geilodates[1]
> date
[1] "2007-07-13"
> class(date)
[1] "Date"
> d=format.Date(date,origin="1970-01-01")
> d
[1] "2007-07-13"
> class(d)
[1] "character"
That looks great, but if I put it into the for-loop:
for(date in geilodates){
+ d=format.Date(date,origin="1970-01-01")
+ }
Error in as.POSIXlt.numeric(x) : 'origin' must be supplied

Comment: @MortenSickel, Maybe you need to track the class of involving variables.