# How to get min of a date column in a data frame using tidyverse and ifelse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

Here is some code illustrating a behavior I don't love:

```
library(tidyverse)

> df <- data.frame(
+   the_date=c(as.Date("2021-01-01"), as.Date("2021-01-02")),
+   keep=c(T, T))

> df %>% summarize(the_min=min(the_date))
     the_min
1 2021-01-01

> df %>% summarize(the_min=min(ifelse(keep, the_date, NA)))
  the_min
1   18628

> df %>% summarize(the_min=as.Date(min(the_date), origin="1970-01-01"))
     the_min
1 2021-01-01
```

In the third case, the minimum of the dates is returned as 18628, whereas I'd like it to be a Date that is `2021-01-01`.  As shown, I can add back the `as.Date` with an origin of `1970-01-01`, but do I have to?

P.S. It's `tidyverse` 1.3.0.

P.P.S. This seems related to [Date shows up as number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496985/date-shows-up-as-number).

Comment: This should cover what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668963/how-to-prevent-ifelse-from-turning-date-objects-into-numeric-objects , e.g.: `dplyr::if_else(1 > 0:1, Sys.Date(), as.Date(NA))` should work how you want it to.

Comment: Ah! If you submit `as.Date(NA)` as an answer, I'll accept it. Or, we could mark this a dup.

Answer (score 0):

If you use case_when steady of ifelse it will work:

```
df %>% summarize(the_min = min(case_when(keep == TRUE ~ the_date)))
```

The case_when function works with the format:
case_when("condition" ~ "result", "condition" ~ result)
If the line does not meet any of the previous conditions, NA is returned.