# What does R think of vector of dates?

Tags: r, date

It's probably gonna be a stupid question, but I can't find the answer quickly and I'm too curious to give up even if late.

In essence, why `1L:3L` and `letters` are both vectors

```
> is.vector(1:3)
[1] TRUE
> is.vector(letters)
[1] TRUE
```

and a sequence of dates is not?

```
x <- structure(1:3, class = "Date")
> is.vector(x)
[1] FALSE
```

From `?vector`

```
The atomic modes are "logical", "integer", "numeric" (synonym "double"),
"complex", "character" and "raw".
```

Fine, clear, even though `x` is atomic...

```
> is.atomic(x)
[1] TRUE
```

So, what makes a dates vector not to be read as vector? (in means of `as.vector()`) and what is there behind this difference?

This question comes from a try to use `embed` with dates which fails cause it wants vector or array. But from a structural point of view I can't see the difference between `1L:10L` and `structure(1L:10L, class="Date")`

Comment: From `?is.vector`: "is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes _other than names_. It returns FALSE otherwise.".

Comment: (i.e. `class` is an attribute.)

Comment: @joran I see, thanks. but it makes no much sense anyway. e.g. to use `embed` I have to convert to number and then back to Date again... it's pointless! What I'm actually asking is why R distinguish between vector of number, char, logical and dates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping over a Date object result in a numeric iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator) - in particular, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143086/)

Comment: R thinks they're nice and punctual but doesn't really want to get into a serious relationship with them. (probably because R still have feelings for a vector of random integers...wild but structured without any of those messy decimals)

Comment: I think your real question then is why does `embed` use `is.vector` rather than, say, `is.atomic`. I'm not sure except to note that the behavior on lists would require some slight tweaking, and inertia. There might be other edge cases that I'm not aware of.

Comment: A message to the R people: Things from which you notice that your naming conventions suck: 1) A vector of dates is not a vector (??) 2) a vector of a non atomic data type (Date) is atomic (??)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few of my comments collected together in an answer:

So, the documentation also says:

> is.vector returns TRUE if x is a vector of the specified mode having no attributes other than names. It returns FALSE otherwise.

So as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator/7143086#7143086) pervious answer, `is.vector` is more like a check on whether a vector has attributes other than names, which certainly may not be obvious.

As for why `embed` behaves the way it does, I'm not sure. It could potentially use `is.atomic` instead, but you'd then have to check for lists separately to achieve the same behavior. There may be some other edge cases I'm overlooking.