# For loop with a date vector

Tags: r, date, for-loop

I am trying to run a for loop that loops through a vector of dates.  However, the behavior is very strange.:

```
library(lubridate)

dates<-ymd(c("2014-12-26","2014-12-19"))
for (run_date in dates) { print(run_date)}
```

As you can see, the dates object looks like the following:

```
> dates
[1] "2014-12-26 UTC" "2014-12-19 UTC"
```

However, what is stored in the run_date variable is the following:

```
> for (run_date in dates) { print(run_date)}
[1] 1419552000
[1] 1418947200
```

Strange behavior and not quite sure what the issue is.  Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: I want to use the "run_date" variable in other places in the code.  However, it's not storing as a date.  it's storing as 1418947200, which I have no idea what format that is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator

Comment: It's the integer value for the `POSIXct` date that you asked it to create with `ymd`. A `str(dates)` will give you `POSIXct[1:2], format: "2014-12-26" "2014-12-19"`.  What do you need the for loop to print?

Comment: use `for (i in seq_along(dates)) { print(dates[i])}`