# how to print date format of POSIXct in r

Tags: r

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-17")  
end <- start + as.difftime(72, units="days")  
for(i in seq(from=start, by=60*60*24*7, to=end)) {  
       print(i)  
}
```

As the codes show above, I try to print out the date after Year 2016 within 72 days. However, the output is always numbers such as 1453006800. I've tried everything I can think of including as.Date, as.Date(i, origin="2016-01-17 00:00:00 EST")....Thanks!

Comment: Try putting `class(i) <- class(start)` before `print(i)`, explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-date-object-result-in-a-numeric-iterator)

Comment: Thanks soooo much!! It finally works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that while "start" and "end" are POSIX date objects, "i" is not. This is evident by checking their structures:

```
> str(start)
 POSIXct[1:1], format: "2016-01-17"
> str(i)
 num 1.46e+09
```

You can use other looping function instead of "for", which seem to be coercing "i" to numeric. You can use a `while` loop like:

```
> i = start
> while (i < end) {
 i = i + 60*60*24*7
 print(i)
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response! solution from  Hadd E. Nuff : class(i) <- class(start) works quite well!