# R programming: invalid "trim" argument

Tags: r

```
URL <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/"

start_date <- as.Date("2011-12-30")
end_date <- as.Date("2012-01-04")
dates_range <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "days")

for (date in dates_range) {
  result <- paste(URL, format(date, "%Y-%m-%d"), ".csv", sep = "")
  print(result)
}
```

I have this set of code over here and it keeps saying:

> "Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  :
> invalid 'trim' argument"

I am expecting the output of:

"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2011-12-30.csv"

"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2011-12-31.csv"

"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2012-01-01.csv"

and so on.

Basically I want to connect the range of dates to the Github links.

Comment: You've hit this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434663/looping-over-a-date-or-posixct-object-results-in-a-numeric-iterator - you have to convert the number back to a date inside your loop `result <- format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%m-%d")` - though as @Friede points out, the loop is not necessary in the first place.

Comment: There should be no need for `format` or for a loop here since the `paste` is vectorized: `paste("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/", seq(as.Date("2011-12-30"), as.Date("2012-01-04"), by = "days"), ".csv", sep = "")`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a loop here. `paste0()`, for instance, is vectorized. Try

```
URL <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/"

start_date <- as.Date("2011-12-30")
end_date <- as.Date("2012-01-04")
dates_range <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "days")
result <- paste0(URL,dates_range, ".csv")
result
```

However, if you like to keep the unnecessary for-loop change to

```
for (i in seq_along(dates_range)) {
  result <- paste(URL, dates_range[[i]], ".csv", sep = "")
  print(result)
}
```

Notice that `paste(sep = "")` is equal to `paste0()`.

---

Execute the following lines and observe the differences.

```
for (date in seq_along(dates_range)) { print(dates_range[[date]]) }
for (date in dates_range) { print(date) }

# the last date in dates_range
class(end_date)
class(format(end_date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
as.numeric(end_date)
```

Comment: Hi Friede, I appreciate your help. What if I want the dates to be changed from "%Y-%m-%d" to "%m-%d-%Y". What am I supposed to do with the code? 

Thanks for your help

Comment: `result <- paste0(URL, format(dates_range, format = "%m-%d-%Y"), ".csv")`

Answer (score 1):

I like `sprintf` in such cases.

```
> sprintf('%s%s.csv', URL, dates_range)
[1] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2011-12-30.csv"
[2] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2011-12-31.csv"
[3] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2012-01-01.csv"
[4] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2012-01-02.csv"
[5] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2012-01-03.csv"
[6] "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/2012-01-04.csv"
```